# How do I read a word from today's log file? In BASH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I need to create a bash script that sends me a notification when the "No valid license found" message is shown.

My log file has logs from 5 years ago. So I need this script to only read the lines from today. (the script will run daily).

So far, I've got here:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
now=$(date)
while read LINE;
do
for WORD in $LINE;
do
if [ "$WORD" == "license" ]
then
echo "the word has been found"
fi
done
done <"text.txt"
```

**How do I only read the lines that start with the current date? Also, I need to search for a phrase, not a single word.**

My log files look like this:

```
2020-12-08 23:55:38 INFO: [system] automatic save: begin
2020-12-08 23:55:39 INFO: [system] automatic save: end
2020-12-09 00:04:32 INFO: [system] user '_internal_suite' logged in
2020-12-09 00:04:32 INFO: [_internal_suite] user '_internal_suite' logged out
2020-12-09 00:04:52 INFO: [system] user 'admin' logged in
2020-12-09 00:04:55 WARNING: [system] error code: 12001 description: no valid license found message: No valid license found.
```

Comment: Is it a requirement to write this script? The typical `grep` command would help otherwise.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes, we lose our license after a restart of services and we need to get notified when this is happening. 
In my scenario, writing this script is the only solution for now.

Comment: My question was more if that was an exercice where you had to write with only Bash commands or if this was for solving a real problem and you can use the best tool for the job. From your answer I get that this is for solving a real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem with `grep` and the `date` command in a single line of Bash:

```
< text.txt grep "^$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") .* No valid license found" && echo Found!
```

This line looks in `text.txt` for a line starting with the current date in the same format as in the file and for the `No valid license found` string. If found, it echoes `Found!` but of course you can replace that part with a `sendmail` command.

Answer (score 1):

You might use GNU `AWK` for that following way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{today=strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}(today==$1 && index($0,"No valid license found")){print}' file.txt
```

where `file.txt` is name of your file. Explanation: I set `today` to current date in YYYY-mm-dd format, then if first column is that day and there is `No valid license found` somewhere in whole line I `print` said line.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

You could use a specific date statement to match the date format of the logfile using awk and than iterate through the lines with an if statement that only does something when the date matches today - like:

```
 date +%Y-%m-%d
```

Which would give you the same date format `2020-12-09`

A script could look like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
NOW=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
while read LINE;
do
if [ $($LINE | awk -F" " {'print $1') == $NOW) ];
then
for WORD in $LINE;
do
if [ "$WORD" == "license" ]
then
echo "the word has been found"
fi
done
fi
done <"text.txt"
```

Comment: You should copy/paste that into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about some of the issues. See also [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out Ed, I‘ll go through it! Bad but used-to habbits die so hard....